# Jquery Validate resetForm does not clear error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using tabs to navigate between forms and when the user presses the next button, form validation takes place.  If there are errors, it will show the summary of errors at the top and also individual errors at each of the fields. The user corrects the errors, and presses the Next button to advance to the next tab. When the press the previous button, the error messages are not cleared.

How would I clear the error container at the top and the individual error messages at each of the form fields provided that the form is valid when pressing the next button.  I have tried the resetForm(), but that didn't work.

Here is my code

```
<form class="wizardTab" id="graph-data">        
  <div class="alert alert-error" id="alert-form-graph-data"></div>
  <div class="row required" id="frmgraphdata">            
    <fieldset>                 
      <legend>Select below</legend>                   
      <div class="inputgroup" id="select_graph_data">                  
        <label for="graph-only">              
          <input class="required" id="graph-only" name="select_graph_or_data" required="required" type="radio" value="graph-only"/>Graph             
        </label>                   
        <label for="data-only">              
          <input class="required" id="data-only" name="select_graph_or_data" required="required" type="radio" value="data-only"/>Data              
        </label>                            
      </div>            
    </fieldset>      
  </div>                   
  <div class="row buttons">                        
    <input class="btnNext" id="q0_btn_next" type="button" value="Next &gt;"/>                   
  </div>             
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
    $('#q0_btn_next').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formID = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
        var form = $('#'+ formID);

        if (form.valid()){

           //code to goto the next tab             

           // clear error message
           form.validate().resetForm();

        }


    });

    $('.wizardTab').each(function(){
    $(this).validate({

        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        validClass: "success",
        errorClass: "error",
        rules: {
            'select_graph_or_data': {
              required: true
            }
            // more rules for other forms
        },

        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

            if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
                return;

            /*$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
                }, 500);*/

        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            if (element.parents('.inputgroup').length) {
                error.insertBefore(element.parents('.inputgroup'));
                element.parents('.inputgroup').addClass('error');
            } else {
                error.insertBefore(element);
            };                     
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList, currentForm) {

            errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
            var formID = this.currentForm.attributes.id.nodeValue;
            var alrt = $('#alert-form-'+ formID);


            if (errors > 0){

                this.defaultShowErrors();

                var msg = '<p>Your form has errors:</p><ul>'; 

                $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
                    msg += '<li><a href="#' + key + '-row" class="error">' + value + '</a></li>';
                });
                msg += '</ul>';                     
                // Show the error in the error summary container
                $('#alert-form-' + formID).html(msg).show();
                $(alrt).html(msg).show();


                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(alrt).offset().top - 20}, 500);

            }



        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you write this code or copy it from someplace?  I ask because the code required to solve this is no more complicated than the code already in place.  BTW, you mention a "previous" button yet there is no such thing shown in your HTML markup.

Comment: @Sparky I wrote the code, but I only copied portions of it. I can add in the previous button

Comment: `resetForm()` is a jQuery Validate method only used for resetting the default error messages on the form.  (Puts the form back to where it started.)  However, if you've placed custom error summaries, you'll have to clear those out yourself.   In addition to the `resetForm()`, just remove the contents of your summary box.   Not really sure how or why you're stuck here.

Comment: @Sparky I have hidden the summary container and that seems to have work. So do you know why the resetForm does not clear the highlighted error and error message at the field level?

Comment: Normally, `resetForm()` should be removing the default `label` elements containing the error messages.  However, your `formID` variable only represents the ID of the form so it's not a proper selector.  Since your `form` variable represents the proper selector, `$('#'+ formID)`, you'll need to use `form.validate().resetForm()` rather than `formID.validate().resetForm()`  See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/

Comment: @Sparky, I have fixed that and thanks for your help.  The error message goes away now. However, would the resetForm also clear the highlighted label as well as I have the highlight and unhighlight methods in the form.validate

Comment: No, AFAIK, it would not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, `resetForm()` should be removing the default label elements containing the error messages.

Your code:

```
var formID = $(this).closest('form').attr('id'); // <- the ID of the form
var form = $('#'+ formID);                       // <- the form object

if (form.valid()){
   formID.validate().resetForm(); // <- should be your `form` variable, not `formID`.
}
```

However, your `formID` variable only represents the ID of the form so it's not a proper selector. Since your `form` variable represents the proper selector, `$('#'+ formID)`, you'll need to use `form.validate().resetForm()` rather than `formID.validate().resetForm()`

See documentation: [jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm)

Comment: I have changed my code to 

form.validate().resetForm();

Comment: @MoxieC, I presumed that you did.   I posted this answer so that you could "accept" it and close out the question.

Comment: I will accept the answer. Does the resetForm take care of the the highlighted error of the fields as well?

Comment: @MoxieC, no, it does not.  It just takes care of the default messages, not anything you're doing with `highlight` and `unhighlight`.